# Error in PostgreSQL trigger

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

i'm coding this trigger in postgreSQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_trg_viabilidad_fila()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
PERFORM S.* 
FROM MontoMinimo M, SolicitudPresupuesto S, Cantidad C, Producto P
WHERE P.idProducto=C.idProducto
and C.idPresupuesto=S.idPresupuesto
and M.idMonto=S.idMonto;
IF (C.cantidad < P.canMinExp OR P.exportable = FALSE)
THEN 
UPDATE SolicitudPresupuesto
SET viable = FALSE
WHERE idPresupuesto = OLD.idPresupuesto;
RETURN NEW;
END IF;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql

CREATE TRIGGER trg_viabilidad_fila BEFORE INSERT
OR UPDATE ON SolicitudPresupuesto
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
fn_trg_viabilidad_fila() ;
```

I can't solve this error..

> An error has occurred: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "c"
>   LINE 1: SELECT C.cantidad < P.canminexp OR P.exportable = FALSE ^
>   QUERY: SELECT C.cantidad < P.canminexp OR P.exportable = FALSE
>   CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function fn_trg_viabilidad_fila() line 9 at IF

I will be very grateful to any help. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the columns of a query outside of the query (or the block where you use the query). You need to store the result of the select somewhere. Additionally you shouldn't run an `UPDATE` on the triggered table, you need to assign the value to the `NEW` record.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_trg_viabilidad_fila()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  l_result boolean;
BEGIN

  SELECT (c.cantidad < p.canMinExp OR p.exportable = FALSE)
    INTO l_result
  FROM MontoMinimo M
    JOIN SolicitudPresupuesto s ON m.idMonto = s.idMonto
    JOIN Cantidad c ON c.idPresupuesto = s.idPresupuesto
    JOIN Producto p ON p.idProducto = c.idProducto;

  IF l_result THEN
    new.viable := false; 
  END IF;

  RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It would be possible to "inline" the query into the `IF` statement but this way it resembles the structure of your current code better. Also note that I replaced the old, outdated implicit joins by an explicit and more robust `JOIN` operator.

The assigment `new.viable` assumes that `idpresupuesto` is the PK in the table `solicitudpresupuesto` (because you used that in the `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE` statement)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am new to programming in this code, and I'm learning. I thank you again!